# MVC 3 - Submitting form through jquery and partial page refresh to show the result after post

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a form in MVC 3. Currently I am doing the following to post the form.
The form is getting posted and it is doing full page refresh to show the result.

After submit the controll will send a status Success or Failure. That's it.
I just need to show in a div the success or failure message based on the returned status.

Does anyone know the highlevel steps on how to do this in MVC 3?

```
<div id="ShowResultHere"></div>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "Test", FormMethod.Post, new { id="frmUpdate"}))
{
   //form fields
   <button type="submit" class="sprt bg_red bt_red h27">Update</button>
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Update(TestModel model)
{
   return Json(new { s = "Success" });
}
```

I want the Success to appear silently inside the ShowResultHere div onsuccess callback.

Can this be done in MVC 3?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could subscribe for the `submit` event of the form and perform the AJAX call, like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#frmUpdate').submit(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(result) {
               // The AJAX call succeeded and the server returned a JSON 
               // with a property "s" => we can use this property
               // and set the html of the target div
               $('#ShowResultHere').html(result.s);
            }
        });
        // it is important to return false in order to 
        // cancel the default submission of the form
        // and perform the AJAX call
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 7):

You can also achieve this by not writing any javascript at all.
By using an AJAX form

```
<div id="ShowResultHere"></div>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Update", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "ShowResultHere" }))
{

}
```

And in your controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Update(TestModel model)
{
    if(blah)
        return PartialView("Success")
    return PartialView("Failed")
}
```

Doing it this way means you have to make two views. But means no writing javascript.

Comment: +1 I like this solution. But you don't need two views necessarily, you could just pass a variable to one view and claim it as success or failure and just use it to show/hide two DIVs instead.

Answer (score 0):

look at this example [Async operations with jQuery Ajax and Asp.Net MVC](http://www.stefanprodan.eu/2011/04/async-operations-with-jquery-ajax-and-asp-net-mvc/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are submitting the form through jQuery Ajax, you could display your message client-side in the success callback function.